# How to include a text file in the built jar? [NetBeans]

Tags: java, file, jar, build, resources

I have a NetBeans project and I have two text files called 'words.txt' and 'letterScores.txt' in the same folder as a .java class, it looks like this:

```
wordfinder.module (Java Package)
    Dictionary.java (Java Class)
    letterScores.txt (text file)
    words.txt (text file)
```

When I run the application from within NetBeans, it works fine. However, when I 'Clean and Build' and run the jar, the text files stop working. The code I'm currently using to get the text files is this (where 'file path' is the full path of the file, alongside BufferedReader etc. to read the files):

```
File wordList = new File(file path);
```

I've read that the files will be included automatically if you put them in the 'src' folder, but I'm not quite sure on the specifics.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: The `src/main/resources` folder is a folder that is supposed to contain **resources** for your application.

Answer (score 0):

File to be read needs to be in classpath if you are just using the filename to read it.

> When I run the application from within NetBeans, it works fine

If you put the file in src folder, so Netbeans will copy the corresponding class files and anything else in your src folder in the generated class folder. So the file will be in the class path and will be found when read.

So package your txt files somewhere in the classpath of your jar or use the full/relative path.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'src' folder, the path containing the files currently looks like this: WordFinder/src/wordfinder/module/...inside the module folder is the Java Class and the two text files.